# Can not start new activity with API21 in eclipse

Tags: android, android-manifest

i have a problem when i start main activity after login. It will be ok if i run app in genymotion API 19. But when i run app in genymotion API 21 It's stop working. It show error:

```
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): Process: vae.vnsupermark.com, PID: 3227
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vae.vnsupermark.com/vae.vnsupermark.com.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot make calls to a recycled instance!
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot make calls to a recycled instance!
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getResourceId(TypedArray.java:694)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at vae.vnsupermark.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:216)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
04-07 00:21:40.776: E/AndroidRuntime(3227):     ... 10 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vae.vnsupermark.com"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.0.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22"

        />

    <!-- for card.io card scanning -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <!-- BLUETOOTH -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

    <!-- GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- gps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="vae.vnsupermark.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="vae.vnsupermark.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- END GCM -->


    <!-- for most things, including card.io & paypal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="vae.vnsupermark.config.ConfigApp"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" >
        <activity

            android:name=".SplashActitvity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/CustomMainActionBarTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" />
        <activity
            android:name="vae.vnsupermark.payment.OnepayCheckout"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" />
        <activity
            android:name="vae.vnsupermark.payment.VtcpayCheckout"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" />
        <activity
            android:name="vae.vnsupermark.payment.PaypalCheckout"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeNoActionbar" />

        <!-- GCM -->
        <receiver
            android:name="vae.vnsupermark.notify.GcmReceiverVNSuper"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="vae.vnsupermark.notify" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="vae.vnsupermark.notify.GcmServiceVNSuper" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- END GCM -->

        <receiver android:name="vae.vnsupermark.notify.WelcomeReceiverVNSuper" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Error Reporter -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.reportOnFroyo"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.targetUrl"
            android:value="http://vnsupermark.com/android/report_error/log_error.php" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.targetEmailSubject"
            android:value="VNSuperMark Report Error" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.targetEmailFrom"
            android:value="VNSuperMark App Android" />

        <service
            android:name="de.quist.app.errorreporter.ExceptionReportService"
            android:process=":exceptionReporter" />

        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

function login()

```
private void login() {
        String username = edtUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
        if (!username.equals("") && !password.equals("")) {
            Store store = Store.getInstances(LoginActivity.this);

            //info user login
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("command", "login");
            params.put("user", username);
            params.put("pass", password);

            if (store != null) { // if get config succcess
                ConfigApp config = (ConfigApp) getApplication();
                taskLoginSever = new TaskLoginSever(LoginActivity.this, params, false, config);
                taskLoginSever.execute(store.getA());
            } else {
                new DialogCustom(LoginActivity.this).showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.error_getconfig));
            }

            //hide keyboard
            Utils.hideKeyboard(LoginActivity.this);
        }
        else {
            if (username.equals("")) {
                edtUsername.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.no_username));
            } 
            if (username.equals("")) {
                edtPassword.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.no_password));
            }

        }
```

Taskloginserver()

```
private void showNotifyLogin(final boolean succcess, String message) {
        final DialogCustom dialog = new DialogCustom(context, R.layout.layout_dialog_notify_login,
                R.id.tv_message, message);

        //object handle
        final Handler handle = new Handler();

        handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // close dialog
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                if( succcess ) {
                    ///show main, if from login activity to main activity
                    // else from main activity to login activity then exit Login UI
                    Bundle bundle = ((LoginActivity)context).getIntent().getExtras();
                    boolean openMain = false; //default open main activity
                    if(bundle != null) {
                        openMain = bundle.getBoolean(config.MAIN_TO_LOGIN_TAG);
                    }
                    if ( !openMain )
                        // open main activitycontext
                        ((LoginActivity) context).openMainActivity();
                    else
                        // finish login activity
                        ((LoginActivity) context).exitLoginUI();
                }

                //remove handle
                handle.removeCallbacks(this);
            }
        } , 1000); //time to show dialog notify login 1s

        //show dilog
        dialog.show();
    }
```

open new activity

```
public void openMainActivity() {
        //start main activity
        Intent intentMain = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentMain);

        //destroy LoginActivity
        exitLoginUI();
    }
```

MainActivity

```
ExceptionReporter.register(this); // report error if app get error
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utils.setDefaultFont(MainActivity.this); // set font for activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        // create database

        try {
            Database.getInstances(MainActivity.this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // view menu
        viewActionShopcart = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.layout_action_shopcart, null);
        tv_quantity_shopcart = (TextView) viewActionShopcart
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_quantity_shopcart);

        // layout left menu
        leftMenu = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_menu);
        drawerLayoutMenu = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_menu);
        drawerListMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_menu);
        headerAccountMenu = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.header_account_menu, null);
        tvNameUser = (TextView) headerAccountMenu
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_name_user);
        tvIdUser = (TextView) headerAccountMenu.findViewById(R.id.tv_id_user);

        imageView = (ImageView) headerAccountMenu.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageflag = (ImageView) headerAccountMenu.findViewById(R.id.imageflag);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String urlRegister = getResources().getString(
                        R.string.Detailaccount);
                // open browser to register page
                Intent itRegister = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(urlRegister));
                startActivity(itRegister);

            }
        });
        tvEmail = (TextView) headerAccountMenu.findViewById(R.id.tv_email_user);
        lnUserInfo = (LinearLayout) headerAccountMenu
                .findViewById(R.id.ln_user_info);
        lnUserLogin = (LinearLayout) headerAccountMenu
                .findViewById(R.id.ln_user_login);
        lnRateApp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln_rate_app);
        tvRate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_rate);
        btnLogin = (Button) headerAccountMenu.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

        // show rate text
        tvRate.setText(String.format(getResources()
                .getString(R.string.rate_app), Utils.getVersion(
                MainActivity.this, 1)));

        // add header user info
        drawerListMenu.addHeaderView(headerAccountMenu);
        // button login when user logout
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new LoginListener());
        lnRateApp.setOnClickListener(new RateAppListenner());

        // function loadgroup asynctask
        titleActionbars = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.title_actionbars2);
        arrayListgroup = new ArrayList<String>();
        displayView(1, null);
        // new TaskRandomNotification(MainActivity.this).execute();
        executeLoadProduct();
        executeLoadProducterm();
        arrayListgroup = TaskLoadProductGroup.getmenunamegroup();
        arraylistgroupterm = TaskLoadProductGroupterm.getmenunamegroup();
        // arrayListgroup.add("VCoin");
        titleActionbars = getTitleActionbars();
        titleActionbar = titleActionbars[0];

        // icons from resources
        iconMenus = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.icon_menus);

        // Recycle the typed array
        iconMenus.recycle();

        drawerListMenu.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        drawerListItemMenu = new ArrayList<DrawerItemMenu>();

        // add home menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[0], iconMenus
                .getResourceId(4, -1), true));

        for (int i = 5; i < titleActionbars.length; i++) {
            // FPT GATE
            drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[i],
                    iconMenus.getResourceId(0, -1), true));

        }
        // add history order menu
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[1], iconMenus
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true));
        // add logout menu when user info is saved on device
        drawerListItemMenu.add(new DrawerItemMenu(titleActionbars[4], iconMenus
                .getResourceId(2, -1), true)); // logout

        adapterMenu = new DrawerMenuAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                drawerListItemMenu);
        drawerListMenu.setAdapter(adapterMenu);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        titleMenu = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                drawerLayoutMenu, R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                setTitle(titleActionbar);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                setTitle(titleMenu);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        // event toggle menu
        drawerLayoutMenu.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        // prepare info
        prepareInfo();
        //load image from url
         GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
            // Execute the task
            task.execute(new String[] { URL });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(1, null);

            // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed
            // with GCM registration.
            regIdGCM();
        }

        // reset quantity on action menu
        resetTextQuantity();
```

Please help me where can i change?

Comment: you did not write activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: put MainActivity code

Comment: yes, i update full my AndroidManifest.xml, please help me about solution?

Comment: Post the code of your activities from which you are switching and to which you are switching

Comment: yes sir, i have post code, please help me!

Comment: Have you used custom styles and attributes for the view ? Not Recycling TypedArray can also lead to this problem. Also try to update to the latest build tool version in your gradle.

Comment: yes, but i code in eclipse.

Comment: Post the code for SplashActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete this line from your MainActivity and run your app

```
iconMenus.recycle();
```